# UIWebView load HTML file from local file system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I load a HTML from the local file system?

I have seen many questions like this but they are all referring to a file that is within a bundle. I would like to load from a path such as`/Users/Abs/Documents/` - I think the ios simulator has access to this as I can save files to my local `/Users/Abs/Documents/` directory.

But I don't know how to load a HTML file to the UIWebView.

How can I edit the below to achieve this:

```
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index.html" ofType @"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/Abs/Documents/index.html"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:req];
```

Note that this is only useful when working in the simulator, because apps on a device are sandboxed and can only get to files in their bundle.

Answer (score 11):

use below code it will work

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
 [webView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```